# Nice book on integrals

Tags: integration, reference-request

On this site I usually see very amazing techniques to solve integrals; contour integrals, differentiating under the integral sign, transforming the integral into a series and son on and so forth.

What I really like is that seemingly difficult integrals become very easy to evaluate; you just need this "a-ah" moment and the right technique.

I know that this skill must be trained, so I would like to find a book or a website which has a collection of such integrals.

I don't mean just difficult integrals, for which you have to work through pages of calculations; I want integrals that are easy to solve if you know how to apply the right technique

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's fine to swallow all these books and to become an integral wizard. But think of the following proverb I once read on a large lollypop: "Look alive – You can be replaced by a button". – Note that the real problem consists in finding an invariant that distinguishes between "integrable" and "nonintegrable" expressions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here are some reference sources:

1. [*Inside Interesting Integrals*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1493912763) by Paul J. Nahin
2. *A Treatise on Integral Calculus [Volume 1](https://archive.org/details/treatiseonintegr01edwauoft)* and *[Volume 2](https://archive.org/details/treatiseonintegr02edwauoft)* by  Joseph Edwards
3. [*Superhuman Integration Techniques*](http://web.mit.edu/~akessler/www/lectures/splash-notes.pdf) by Andre Kessler
4. [*Integration: The Feynman Way*](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-304-undergraduate-seminar-in-discrete-mathematics-spring-2006/projects/integratnfeynman.pdf)
5. [*Wikipedia: Differentiation Under The Integral Sign*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)
6. [*sos440's blog*](http://sos440.tistory.com/category)

Comment: sos440's blog is broken... Can you look after that?

Answer (score 11):

[Irresistible Integrals](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Irresistible-Integrals-Symbolics-Experiments-Evaluation/dp/0521796369) by George Boros and Victor Moll is a fantastic book for all sorts of interesting approaches to integrals.