# Advanced / In-Depth Calculus Book for Self-Edification

Tags: calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am a pre-engineering student currently taking a Single Variable Calculus course at a community college.

I recognize that my future success (or not so much) as an engineer will be based, in large part, on my capabilities with and understanding of Calculus. Therefore, I really, really want to master it like I've never mastered any subject before.

I'm doing well in my class, and my instructor is great, but I am under the impression that this course and it's textbook ([Calculus, Early Transcendentals by Stewart](http://amzn.com/1111426686)) do not delve quite as deeply into Calculus as I would like. Also, the textbook frequently introduces new techniques and concepts with little to no explanation.

(Incidentally, I'm a self-taught software developer, so I am adept at learning new topics on my own. Learning Mathematics is, IMHO, quite similar to learning a new programming language.)

So I'm hoping to find some really excellent Calculus textbooks that will give me deep insight into the topics of differentiation and integration (and any other topics my course may be missing).

I've used Google and my school's library to search extensively, and I've found no shortage of Calculus textbooks. My problem is that, since I'm just now learning the basics, I have no way to know just how in-depth an advanced or in-depth book should go, or what important information my current textbook may be missing.

I own a copy of [The Calculus Lifesaver, by Adrian Banner](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8351.html), which is absolutely outstanding. If anyone reading this happens to be struggling with Calculus, this is the book to turn to.

I also have been taking advantage of the Calculus courses in MIT's OpenCourseware. Calculus Revisited, with Herbert Gross, has been very helpful. His way of explaining the concepts just really "clicks" with me.

So, with that said, I'm just hoping the experts in the community here can recommend some great resources (e.g. books, free online courses, or other media) to help me optimize my knowledge of Calculus.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe [this answer of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1096791/146687) would help.

Comment: I would suggest "A Course of Pure Mathematics" by G. H. Hardy. It delves really deep into the subject matter and is specially designed for students of age around 15-16 years. Spivak's Calculus also does the same thing he needs too many pages and writes in a style which removes all the "inspirational stuff" from the subject matter.

Comment: I agree with the answers suggesting *Calculus* by Tom Apostol, if you want a course that includes both theory (i.e. detailed proofs) and practice at a high level. If that's too difficult, *Calculus* by Marsden and Weinstein is a good alternative, as is *A First Course in Calculus* by Lang. These could be described as intermediate in difficulty and rigour between Apostol and Stewart. Lang has slightly more rigorous theory, Marsden and Weinstein a greater number of computational practice exercises, which nonetheless tend to be more instructive and varied than the ones in Stewart.

Comment: Let me add that Apostol has a number of real-world applications throughout the book, especially from physics; that's one of its characteristics.

Comment: @Venus Yes, thank you - that was helpful. My class begins integration in two weeks, and I've been reading ahead a bit, but I could definitely stand some more enlightenment in that area.

Comment: @Keith I've been meaning to set aside some time to learn more about math notation and mathematic induction, so I can understand some of the more rigorous stuff. But so far, I've been too busy with my classes. So I'll check those out, and hopefully will be able to appreciate the more rigorous expositions soon.

Comment: @keith It must be really outstanding to have so many great recommendations. Is it pretty easy to find used copies of it? I mean, aside from ordering from Amazon or elsewhere online, is it likely to be in a local library or used bookstore, if they have a decent mathematics section?

Comment: @waveslider It's fairly easy to find some of these books on the internet. There are websites you can download them from. In the case of Marsden and Weinstein's book, it can be downloaded directly from the Caltech website, the first volume here: http://authors.library.caltech.edu/25030/ There are three volumes, and also three volumes to the student companion guide to the book. If you're looking for where the books are available in libraries, try worldcat.org (enter your city). I think it's hit-and-miss for used books locally. You can try online at abebooks.com or amazon.com.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know they were available to download. That's nice. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @keith Just FYI: I noticed that Apostol's Calculus Volume I is the textbook for MIT's advanced version of 1801, 18013A Calculus with Theory. That's quite an endorsement. I ended up purchasing Introduction to Calculus and Analysis I by Richard Courant, but I also found Apostol's first volume online and am reading that as well. I'm going to have to first learn the notation, but it is obviously a huge improvement over Stewart's books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend *Advanced Calculus* by G. B. Folland. It is rigorous and still elegant, especially when it comes to vector calculus.

Comment: While all of the recommendations everyone has made are excellent, especially Spivak's Calculus (I've seen that book recommended frequently), I must chose this response, because one [introduction to Folland's book](http://math-blog.com/2007/05/13/the-most-enlightening-calculus-books/) (linked for posterity) that I read said it has an abundance of physics examples, which will be helpful to me as an engineering student. Thank you, everyone!

Comment: Sorry to say, but in your link, it only says that *Introduction to Calculus and Analysis* by Richard Courant and Fritz John provides a lot of motivation with abundance of physics applications.

Comment: You may be right that I misunderstood the description, but I don't believe so. It said (this is copied & pasted): "The abundance of physics applications, make it ideal for physics majors and engineers..." I understood an "abundance of physics applications" to mean examples of physics applications.

Comment: @Masacroso Have you checked this(https://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Calculus-Gerald-B-Folland/dp/0130652652)?

Answer (score 11):

From what I gather the holy grail of calculus books seems to be Calculus by Micheal Spivak.

Comment: Just keep in mind this book is for mathematicians, so you'd like to have another book where you can practice the methods described in here.

Comment: That sounds right - some of the older Calculus textbooks I've looked at are so rigorous that I realized I would need a textbook on Mathematic Notation just to keep up. But, it wouldn't be a bad idea to read one of those, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend the two volumes of Calculus by T. Apostol, they are a classic.

Comment: Thanks - I will have to get that Apostol's books. So many people recommend it; not only here but all over the internet, so I reckon it must be really good.

Comment: You are welcome, I am sure you will enjoy it, and I think it suits your purpose very well. I must confess myself, that it was only after many years that I came to realise what a jewel those books are.

Answer (score 2):

If you want CALCULUS to be fun, you can also read these two along with Spivak

- [Calculus for Dummies](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118791290)
- [Calculus II for Dummies](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/111816170X)

Don't just go on there names, these are not only for Dummies. Here is what author has to say-
[image]

I personally like those books which talks to you while you are reading them. It does and it is humorous too!

Comment: Since you like books with a more personal, colloquial tone than the typical textbook, you may like The Calculus Lifesaver book I mentioned in my question, by Adrian Banner. It is written on a personal level and contains frequent jokes, many of which are even funny. ;)

Comment: Yup. I  already ordered it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've collected a couple "for dummies" books over the years, and they're usually pretty good, although the series title is the worst marketing ploy I've ever encountered.

Answer (score 1):

When I was a freshman in college, we used *Calculus* by Tom Apostol. It took me many years to appreciate its greatness. However, if you'd like to learn the subject in depth, this book is really worth sinking your teeth into.

Comment: I do - Calculus seemed intimidating at first, but only because of hype, I think. The more I get to know it, the more in awe I am. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Ross' *Elementary Analysis: The Theory of Calculus*. After reading that, you should peruse Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* since it is the indisputable bible of elementary analysis.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer more than once.  If one answer addresses multiple questions, please consider flagging those questions as duplicates.  If the questions are distinct, please craft answers which address those distinctions.

Comment: Also, you claim that Baby Rudin is the "indisputable bible of elementary analysis."  Please allow me to dispute that claim.  Baby Rudin is a classic text, but it is *not* good for learning---it is a reference.  Rudin focuses on "elegance" and clever tricks which often hide what should be intuitive ideas.  I have respect for Rudin's work, but the cultish reverence a large number of people have for the text is confusing to me.

Comment: Most of the exercises in undergraduate textbooks are artificial and quite unlike research problems. They usually involve piecing together a few definitions and theorems, so Rudin's text isn't alone in this regard. I admire Rudin's text for its elegant and concise exposition and because its exercises force students to think deeply about concepts. That is, I think, the purpose of a real analysis course: to teach students to think in a novel and more profound way about the discipline of mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend *Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Differential Forms: A Unified Approach* by John H. Hubbard and Barbara Burke Hubbard. (Get it off their [website](https://matrixeditions.com/), it is far cheaper than copies off Amazon)

Given that you are a student of engineering, it is important to feel comfortable with the coexistence of linear algebra with calculus, which is something many calculus textbooks miss (because linear algebra typically isn't a prerequisite for calculus)!

Furthermore, this book will cover vector calculus in the more general setting of manifolds, giving you the deep dive I think you're looking for. There is a thorough, deep chapter on single and multivariable integration, with a short treatise to Lebesgue integration. This book discusses differential forms in depth, a topic many calculus textbooks overlook (it also discusses their applications).

I'll leave you with the author's agenda lined out in the preface:

*First, we believe that at this level linear algebra should be a more convenient setting and language for multivariate calculus than a subject in its own right. The guiding principle of this unified approach is that locally, a nonlinear function behaves like its derivative.*

*Second, we emphasize computationally effective algorithms, and we prove theorems by showing that these algorithms work.*

*Third, we use differential forms to generalize the fundamental theorem of calculus to higher dimensions.*